# Override HttpRequest validation error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My Web API currently returns custom errors. By default the Web API returns error message if the json object is not built correctly. I'm wondering if there's a way we can override the error message from the API layer to send my current custom exception object?

Sample - `TestException.cs`:

```
public string Message { get; set; }
public string StatusCode { get; set; }
.....
```

Error message from API layer:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-345m34u50mw345u0w34m5034m5-34m5iw3m45wm345w345345-01",
    "errors": {
        "request": [
        "The request field is required."
            ],
        "$.data.city": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.data.city | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 6."
            ]
    }
}
```

I'd like to do something like below if it's possible. Maybe some kind of middleware?

```
throw new TestException(apiValidation.status, apiValidation.errors)
```

Comment: Throwing an exception is not the same as returning a response. Are you saying that instead of returning a human readable response for a Bad Request, you want to throw an exception and let the application crash? Or how should that exception be handled?

Answer (score 0):

This response is called [Problem details](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807), you can override its content by adding `builder.Services.AddProblemDetails` with a configuration delegate. In the example below I demonstrate its capabilities - you can remove and extend its properties, access services using HttpContext.RequestServices and so on.

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(configure =>
{
    configure.CustomizeProblemDetails = options =>
    {
        options.ProblemDetails.Extensions.Add("test_field", "test_value");

        if (options.ProblemDetails is ValidationProblemDetails validationProblemDetails)
        {
            validationProblemDetails.Errors.Add("inserted_field", new [] { "inserted_value1", "inserted_value2" });
        }
        
        // you can resolve services as well
        var service = options.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<Service>();
    };
});
```

I tested my code with .NET 7 and the code above was enough, but I also see some articles that require following line in app configuration

```
app.UseProblemDetails();
```

Response:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-79395ec25c676e2391a917e59ba19f17-7948e802536d2a94-00",
  "test_field": "test_value",
  "errors": {
    "test": [
      "The test field is required."
    ],
    "$.request": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.request | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 14."
    ],
    "inserted_field": [
      "inserted_value1",
      "inserted_value2"
    ]
  }
}
```